# OmniAuth OAuth2 how to access to a strategy -> client? so that I can refresh token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth

## background

I have an omniauth-oauth2 subclass strategy working on my rails app.  When to refresh access_token, I see I need to create `OAuth2::AccessToken`.  But to create it, it seems it requires `OAuth2::Client` which I think can obtain from "omniauth-oauth2 subclass strategy."

found this solution [Refresh token using Omniauth-oauth2 in Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707734/refresh-token-using-omniauth-oauth2-in-rails-application)
This is how they solved to obtain a strategy

```rb
# the initial param:nil is meant to be a rack object, but since 
# we don't use it here, we give it a nil
strategy = OmniAuth::Strategies::YOUR_PROVIDER.new nil, client_id, client_secret
client = strategy.client

your_expired_at_from_your_provider = Time.now.to_i

hash = {
  access_token: "your access_token from your provider",
  refresh_token: "your refresh_token from your provider",
  expires_at: your_expired_at_from_your_provider,
}
access_token_object = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(client, hash)
access_token_object.refresh!
```

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/blob/v1.6.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L132
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/blob/v1.4.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb#L35
https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb#L12
https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/v1.4.0/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb#L82

## problem

What I don't understand is, it looks a bit of hacky ways to create a strategy by giving `nil` to the first argument.

"omniauth-oauth2 subclass strategy" is in rack (like the image below), so I am thinking there is a way to access to a strategy from rack middleware, somewhere?

[image]

## question

Is creating a strategy like above is the only way to refresh token?
`strategy -> client -> access_token_object -> refresh!`

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a right way, but make a workaround for my custom omniauth strategy:

```
class MyOrg < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
  #...
  info do
    {
      'email'        => extra['user'].try(:[], 'email'),
      # ...
      'get_org' => Proc.new do
        get_org
      end
    }
  end

  def get_org
    @org ||= begin
      org_id = extra['user'].try(:[], 'org_id')
      access_token.get(options[:client_options][:site] + "/v1/orgs/#{org_id}").parsed
    end
  end


end
```

Then call it as:

```
hash[:info][:get_org].call
```

Answer (score -1):

I leveraged the `oauth2` gem to do the refreshing. Here's a complete solution for using the omniauth strategy to access the google APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191048/2672869