# Best practice to manage google oauth token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-oauth

I'm making web app using google [calendar api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/).

In this app, I request user to authorize Google Calendar Access with [Google Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) on register.

My problem is a token returned has expires in 1 hours, so users have to authorize everytime.

I understand I can't change expire time in Google API.

My question is how can I keep oauth token active?

Do I have to make cron updating token with refresh token?

thanks,

Comment: If you have the refresh URI, why not do what Google's client libraries do - attempt to refresh if expired, and raise / reprompt if no access is obtained.

Comment: Thank you techhowch.
You mean Google client libraries automatically update token?

Comment: I use this library https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 with rails

It means client library automatically update token with application process background, even if user doesn't access application for long time?
> handle refresh for you when the access token is no longer valid

Comment: That is not one of Google's client libraries

Comment: ah sorry, I use this one https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client

Comment: similar post here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707734/refresh-token-using-omniauth-oauth2-in-rails-application

Comment: If you have specific language and client libraries of relevance, consider adding those tags to your question to help your question find the correct audience.

Answer (score 0):

I've found docs about auto  on java

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

> An access token typically has an expiration date of 1 hour, after
>   which you will get an error if you try to use it. GoogleCredential
>   takes care of automatically "refreshing" the token, which simply means
>   getting a new access token

I'm wondering Ruby also has the auto update.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/web-app#exchange-authorization-code

> After a user grants offline access to the requested scopes, you can
>   continue to use the API client to access Google APIs on the user's
>   behalf when the user is offline. The client object will refresh the
>   access token as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get answer by asking on Github issue

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/719